# How to perform a simple json post with spray-json in spray?

Tags: scala, spray, spray-json

I'm trying to perform a simple json post with spray. But it seems that i can get an http entity for a json object that can be Marshall.

here is my error:

> [error]
>   ...../IdeaProjects/PoolpartyConnector/src/main/scala/org/iadb/poolpartyconnector/thesaurusoperation/ThesaurusCacheService.scala:172:
>   could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type
>   spray.httpx.marshalling.Marshaller[spray.json.JsValue]
>
> [error]     val request            =
>   Post(s"$thesaurusapiEndpoint/$coreProjectId/suggestFreeConcept?",
>   suggestionJsonBody)

and the code that comes with it:

```
 override def createSuggestedFreeConcept(suggestedPrefLabel: String, lang: String, scheme: String, b: Boolean): String = {

    import system.dispatcher
    import spray.json._

    val pipeline      = addCredentials(BasicHttpCredentials("superadmin", "poolparty")) ~> sendReceive


    val label              = LanguageLiteral(suggestedPrefLabel, lang)
    val suggestion         = SuggestFreeConcept(List(label), b, Some(List(scheme)), None, None,None, None)
    val suggestionJsonBody = suggestion.toJson

    val request            = Post(s"$thesaurusapiEndpoint/$coreProjectId/suggestFreeConcept?", suggestionJsonBody)

    val res                = pipeline(request)

    getSuggestedFromFutureHttpResponse(res) match {

      case None => ""
      case Some(e) => e

    }
  }
```

Please, does any one has an idea of what is going on with the implicit marshaller. I though spray Json would come with implicit marshaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how i solved it:

```
override def createSuggestedFreeConcepts(suggestedPrefLabels: List[LanguageLiteral], scheme: String, checkDuplicates: Boolean): List[String] = {


    import system.dispatcher

    import spray.httpx.marshalling._
    import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport._

    val pipeline      = addCredentials(BasicHttpCredentials("superadmin", "poolparty")) ~> sendReceive


    suggestedPrefLabels map { suggestedPrefLabel =>

      val suggestion    = SuggestFreeConcept(List(suggestedPrefLabel), checkDuplicates, Some(List(Uri(scheme))), None, None, None, None)
      val request       = Post(s"$thesaurusapiEndpoint/$coreProjectId/suggestFreeConcept", marshal(suggestion))

      val res           = pipeline(request)

      getSuggestedFromFutureHttpResponse(res) match {

        case None => ""
        case Some(e) => e

      }

    }

  }
```

the key is:

> import spray.httpx.marshalling._ import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport._

and

> val request       =
>   Post(s"$thesaurusapiEndpoint/$coreProjectId/suggestFreeConcept",
>   marshal(suggestion))

I marshall suggestion. The explanation is not super super straightforward. But by fetching around in the doc, it is explained.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you already have a custom Json Protocol somewhere so that `suggestion.toJson` works correctly?

Try the following:

```
val body = HttpEntity(`application/json`, suggestionJsonBody.prettyPrint)
val request = Post(s"$thesaurusapiEndpoint/$coreProjectId/suggestFreeConcept?", body)
```

you could also use `compactPrint` rather than `prettyPrint`, in either case, it turns the Json into a string containing the json information.